# Memory leak while using C# dll in a C++

Tags: c#, c++, memory, dll, memory-leaks

The situation is, I wrapped C# dll to use it in a C++ project and when I execute C++ project I can't see any sign about memory leak but the memory increases little by little. I think it's because the GC in C# library doesn't work in C++ project and I don't know how to solve it. Please help me.

My code is below:

1. C#

```
    using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    namespace CSharpLib
    {

        [Guid("8EA9EAA8-CA3D-4584-B1E0-7B9561757CA4")]
        public interface ICSharpLibrary
        {
            int[] GetData();
            string GetName();
            bool Init();
        }

        [Guid("B62A2B51-621D-41AA-8F4F-021E404B593C")]
        public class CSharpLibrary : ICSharpLibrary, IDisposable
        {
            private bool disposed = false;

            private int[] data;

            private string name = "CSharpLib";

            private SafeHandle safeHandle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);

            private void MakeData()
            {
                var list = new List<int>();
                var rnd = new Random();
                for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    list.Add(rnd.Next(0, 255));
                }
    
                data = list.ToArray();
            }
    
            public int[] GetData()
            {
                MakeData();
                return data;
            }
    
            public string GetName()
            {
                return name;
            }
    
            public bool Init()
            {
                data = null;
    
                return true;
            }
    
            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispose(true);
            }
    
            protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposed)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (disposing)
                {
                    data = null;
                    safeHandle.Dispose();
                }
    
                disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

2. C++

```
    #pragma once
    
    #ifdef CPLUSLIBRARY_EXPORTS
    #define CPLUSLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define CPLUSLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
    
    extern "C" CPLUSLIBRARY_API bool Init();
    
    extern "C" CPLUSLIBRARY_API int* GetData();
    
    extern "C" CPLUSLIBRARY_API char* GetName();
```

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include "pch.h"
    #include "CPlusLibrary.h"
    
    #import "lib/CSharpLibrary.tlb" no_namespace named_guids
    
    ICSharpLibrary* lib = NULL;
    int* data = NULL;
    bool isWorking = false;
    char* name = NULL;
    
    bool Init() {
        HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, tagCOINIT::COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    
        if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
            return false;
    
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CSharpLibrary, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICSharpLibrary, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&lib));
    
        if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
            return false;
    
        return true;
    }
    
    int* GetData() {
        auto raw = lib->GetData();
        void* pVoid = NULL;
    
        HRESULT hr = ::SafeArrayAccessData(raw, &pVoid);
    
        if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
            return NULL;
        auto result = reinterpret_cast<int*>(pVoid);
    
        return result;
    }
    
    char* GetName() {
        char str[10];
        strcpy_s(str, lib->GetName());
        name = str;
    
        return name;
    }
```

3. executor

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <CPlusLibrary.h>
    #include <CoreWindow.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        if (!Init())
            return 0;
    
        while (true) {
            auto name = GetName();
            std::cout << name << std::endl;
            auto data = GetData();
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                std::cout << data[i];
            }
    
            std::cout << std::endl;
    
            Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The use of `auto` here makes it impossible to see exactly what is going on.  The [documentation for `#import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp) indicates that it does use smart pointers for interface pointers.  It doesn't mention whether smart pointer wrappers are or are not used for SAFEARRAY and BSTR, which is critically important to understanding this code.  I *think* that because the `raw_native_types` attribute is not specified on the import, `_bstr_t` wrappers are in use.  Still no indication on whether SAFEARRAY is wrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SafeArrayAccessData  documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearrayaccessdata)

> After calling SafeArrayAccessData, you must call the SafeArrayUnaccessData function to unlock the array.

Not sure this is the actual reason for the leak. But when debugging problems, a good first step is to ensure you are following all the rules specified in the documentation.

Comment: It's worse.  Depending on the options with which the type library is converted to a C++ wrapper, either it's working with raw SAFEARRAY and BSTR which need to be manually freed, or else the SAFEARRAY and BSTR are freed by a smart pointer at the end of the scope, in which case `GetData()` returns a dangling pointer into a freed array.

Comment: @Ben Voigt you seem to more about this than me. I mostly thought it odd that there was no resource cleanup at all. I'm mostly used to interfacing from c# to c++. I think it would be useful if you could write an answer explaining the problems in greater detail.

Comment: Unfortunately the part I'm not familiar with (default behavior of `#import`) is rather key to knowing what's going on here.  I'm not confident whether `auto raw = lib->GetData();` is declaring a `_variant_t`, a `SAFEARRAY*`, or some other SAFEARRAY wrapper that implicitly converts allowing it to be directly used with `SafeArrayAccessData`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helps me a lot! I didn't know well about SAFEARRAY, and the reason was that I didn't call SafeArrayUnaccessData and SafeArrayDestroy functions.